# Indexed data is not displaying on storefront

Tags: xml, solr, websphere-commerce

I have followed this tutorial

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZLC2_7.0.0/com.ibm.commerce.developer.doc/tutorial/tsd_search1_intro.htm?lang=en

I have inserted the required configuration that are mentioned in the tutorial in the `schema.xml` and `wc-data-config.xml` files. I have also added the new search profile for those custom tables.
 But, after preproccessing and buildindex processes, I can't see the indexed values of the custom tables on the storefront. Later, I have checked for preprocess files but I haven't noticed any trace of custom tables in them.

Comment: Please send the part of code you added to the configuration files.

Comment: http://localhost/solr/MC_10151_CatalogEntry_en_US/select?q=catentry_id:13901 I can see the contents within this url but not on the store front. Do you have any idea? Thanks

Comment: Try to use `http://localhost/solr/MC_10151_CatalogEntry_en_US/admin/file/?file=schema.xml` to get configuration files. Just change the file name on the url tail.

Comment: I can see the fields that I have inserted in the schema.xml and also in the url that I have provided above but I cannot see the same content in the store front when I search for it

Comment: Maybe this presentation could be helpful. http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27038713&aid=1. If not please provide me more information about the inserted lines in all files.

Comment: Thanks Bruno. My issue is resolved, I gave catentry_id's of catenttype_id 'productbean' instead of 'itembean' as per tutorial in the xwarranty and xcareinstruction tables. Now, I can see the content on the store

Answer (score 0):

parts of this tutorial are valid only for FEP6 and prev versions

if you have fep7 or fep8, please note that search profiles , mediators are configured in WCDE_ENT70\workspace\Search\xml\config\com.ibm.commerce.catalog

generally all configuration for search are in Search , Search-rest projects .

if you have fep7 or fep8 , all results are returned as JSON views, please continue reading how to add custom postprocessor (to include extra fields to search results ) 
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZLC2_7.0.0/com.ibm.commerce.developer.doc/tasks/tsdsearchcustqpost.htm?lang=en

look at the attached zip sample http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZLC2_7.0.0/com.ibm.commerce.developer.doc/code/SearchCustomizationAssets.zip?lang=en-us how to add the custom field into UserData map in mediator (it is a little different the fep6 )

hope this give you enough info to complete your example .

Thanks
Abed

Comment: Hello Yaseen, Thanks for your reply. I have been working on FEP 5 and my issue also has been resolved, it is the problem with catentry_id's which I have inserted.